# How do I convert a Mac OS Filemaker 2 database to a recent FM or Bento db, preserving the relations and field data types

Tags: database, format, filemaker

I'm hoping for more than just exporting the data, I would like to preserve the relation between the databases. This is for a friend's legacy database that tracks monthly fees from a list of clients.

I have the original FM database file on hand, but **not** the machine it ran on with the old version of Filemaker 2. Recent versions won't import it, saying it's too old.

If there is a Mac-only solution that **would** make things simpler for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an app that will open them and convert them. At least to something else, then you can bring it back in.

http://www.fmpromigrator.com/products/fmpro_migrator/index.html

You might also want to track down a version on versiontracker.

http://www.versiontracker.com/dyn/moreinfo/macosx/211788&vid=47765&mode=info

Answer (score 0):

I eventually solved this by acquiring Filemaker II and opening it a PowerPC Mac running Mac OS 10.4 (Tiger). I then took screenshots of all the field definitions, calculation formulas and layouts. Since the database only had 2 related files and no scripts, it was relatively easy, if tedious. I then recreated everything using a trial copy of FM version 10.

On an hourly basis it was cheaper than the $100 fmpromigrator, although I would buy that in a heartbeat if this was a paying gig. It seems like a very complete solution.

While I didn't try Daniel's solution, I believe it would have worked, so he gets the correct answer. I just wanted to post my solution as well.